# Is there a built in function for rounding a double in java

Tags: java

I want to round a double to a specific amount of decimal places in java. Is there a specific function for doing so and can this function round the double to an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `Math.round()` that will return the rounded `long` value.

You can also cast a `double` value to a `long` or an `int`.

If you need to format the double value to a specific number of decimals then use `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: Is it possible to round to a specific amount of decimal values using this function?

Answer (score 0):

`DateFormat df = new DateFormat("#.##");`

The above statement can bring your double value to a specific format.

`double d = Math.round(43.475);`

The above statement can round your double value.